# Clamav milter forward a copy of infected emails

Tags: postfix, clamav

I have a working postfix + clamav installation. 
How can I configure this to not just quarantene infected emails but if this happens also send a copy of the email to the sysadmins address?

What I found in clamav-milter.conf is:

```
VirusAction /usr/local/bin/virus.pl
RejectMsg "REJECT - AntiVirus detected: %v"
```

But virus.pl only generates a virus warning message what's sent back to the client. The script does not get the infected letters message body.

I could easily modify this just to get an alert with the virus-es name to the sysadmins but what I want is that the actual message to be forwarded to us.

Thanks

Comment: What's the content of `/usr/local/bin/virus.pl`? Is that script just your own-developed script or from some package?

Answer (score 1):

```
#clamav-milter.conf
OnInfected Quarantine
VirusAction /usr/local/bin/virus.pl
```

Extract from [clamav-milter.conf man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/clamav-milter.conf/)

- `Quarantine` - message  is quarantined  instead  of being delivered. NOTE: In `Sendmail` the quarantine queue can be examined via `mailq -qQ`. For `Postfix` this  causes  the message to be placed on `hold`
- `VirusAction /usr/local/bin/virus.pl` - Execute  a  command  (possibly  searching PATH) when an infected message is found. The following parameters  are  passed  to  the invoked  program  in  this  order: `virus name, queue id, sender,destination, subject, message id, message date`.

You can use the queue id passed as an argument in the script to get the actual mail content using `postcat -q <queue id>` and email the same to your administrator. Hope this helps.